# Make call from website and interpret speech

Tags: speech-recognition, telephony

I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is, so I thought i'd ask you clever people.

I want to create a website where users will be able to input their phone number.

Once they do, I want the "site" to call them and play an automated message, then wait for their input as speech (i.e.: "would you like a banana?" user:"yes")

I then need to interpret that speech and make the website reflect the selected action.

So far my conclusion is that I'd need to:

1. create a telephony system (i was looking at Asterisk),
2. tie that into a VOIP service to make calls to actual numbers
3. Stream speech into Speech Recognition Engine (I looked at LumenVox and Nuance Recogniser)
4. Get the output from the speech recog engine and parse the text

It seems so ridiculously complicated though.
Setting up Asterisk is, in itself, a massive pain. After 5 days of tinkering with it, I still can't get it to make a phone call.

Would you know of any alternative ways of achieving this?

Cheers,
Andre

Comment: In short: No. The route you outlined sounds like the easiest; as you note, `easiest != easy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hobbling together a system like this using open source and other components will be painful and time consuming.  I would recommend using a fully functioning IVR system that has all of the components you already need in a single system where you can just focus on the application and not getting all of the pieces working together.  I would recommend using [Voxeo Prophecy](http://www.voxeo.com/products/voicexml-ivr-platform.jsp) because it is easy to use, priced competitively, provides a hosted and on-premise solution, and developers can develop and test their applications for free.  On this platform you could put together a full proof of concept with basically no cost to you. It comes with the Speech Recognition Engine, Text-To-Speech, and allows you to make outbound calls using the W3C standard called [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/).  If you do not want to take the time learn CCXML you could use something like [Chrysalis Notification Service](http://www.chrysalis.net/Home/News/PressReleases/ChrysalisNotificationService/tabid/167/Default.aspx) which is a hosted service or premise-based solution that lets you make outbound calls through an API or through its web interface.  It integrates in with Prophecy and the folks at Chrysalis have put together systems just like the one you are describing with these products.  If you use Prophecy you will put together the voice application to prompt the users for their responses using another [W3C standard called VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/).  This is a web based standard so it makes it easy to integrate in with the web application for initiating the call and updating user responses.

Comment: Voxeo is amazing. I got it working really quickly within minutes and their support is pretty great.

Comment: Andre - Glad to hear you got such great results.  Voxeo is amazing.  What amazes me about them is the level of support you get from them even when you have not purchased anything from them.  I find them extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To type the numbers by voice you don't need asterisk and conventional telephony. You can use red5-based ASR service communicating over RTMP protocol and javascript API to hangle flash object to record sound. You can find some interesting examples of that on

http://speechapi.com

See demos here

http://speechapi.com/demos/home/

its using open source CMUSphinx speech recognition system for decoding  for example you can plug very accurate digit-only TIDIGITs model. See more information on the website

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

and highly customizable for your needs

You can install the service on your host, you can just download the installation from sourceforge project page

https://sourceforge.net/projects/speechcloud/

Answer (score 1):

There are hosted services that may be able to help you.

For outbound calling, touch tone interaction, sending SMS messages, and other telephony goodness http://www.twilio.com/ is very popular. Last time I looked, Twilio did not do Speech Recognition or text to speech synthesis.

For Speech Recognition and Text to speech synthesis, you may want to to look at [Nuance](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php), [Yapme](http://yapme.com/speech-cloud.html), [ispeech.org](http://www.ispeech.org/developers), [vlingo](http://www.vlingo.com/), or others. Nuance has improved their developer program and will now give you [free access to their services](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php) for development. Yap (I believe) was recently [purchased by Amazon](http://techcrunch.com/2011/11/09/amazon-snaps-up-yap-and-its-voice-recognition-technology/), so we may see some changes their service. [Vlingo was purchased by Nuance](http://www.engadget.com/2011/12/21/nuance-gobbles-up-vlingo-yearns-to-transcribe-its-own-announcem/), so not sure of its status now.

There are many expensive hosted service that can help you (Convergys, TellMe, Voxeo and others). I've heard of less expensive hosted IVR services, but haven't used them. Look at [Angel](http://www.angel.com/) or [Metaphor IVR](http://www.metaphortech.com/) and see if they meet your needs.